# Vue js component un-renders when I update value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So I have pretty length vue application which I can't really paste here but I'll do my best to explain what is happening.

So I have a vue application and 3 components: comp1, comp2 and comp3.

`comp1` an `comp2` render just fine but for some reason when I try rendering `comp3`: `comp1` and `comp2` un-render by themselves (update event triggers or something).

`comp3` only uses `pickedItems` variable which isn't used by `comp1` and `comp2`.

My root vue application has that data property defined like this:

```
data: {
    ...
    //Items to pick from in individual mode
    pickedItems: []
    ...
},
```

Then in my template Im doing something like this:

```
<div v-for="(wgt, idx) in cb.widgets" class="cb-wgt"> 
...
    <div class ="wgt">
        <button type="search" class="btn btn-default" v-on:click.prevent="searchForContent(idx)">Search</button>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

And the code for `searchForContent` looks like like this:

```
searchForContent(idx) {
    var that = this;
    var wgt = that.widgets[idx];

    var s = wgt.search ? wgt.search : "";

    var promise = $.ajax({
        url: '/landings/get_data',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {search: s},
        timeout: 600
    }).done(function(ajaxResponse) {
        //vue.set(that.pickedItems, idx, ajaxResponse.pickedItems);

        that.pickedItems[idx] = ajaxResponse.pickedItems;
        console.log('that.pickedItems', that.pickedItems);
    }).fail(function(response) {
    });
},
```

but the moment I set `that.pickedItems[idx]` -> `comp1` and `comp2` disappear - why? 
Im a newb in vue and spent hours trying to figure this out already, hoping for some pointers.

**UPDATE 1**

I think my issues is related to this (from vue docs):

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following
>   changes to an array: When you directly set an item with the index,
>   e.g.   `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`   To overcome caveat, both
>   of the following will accomplish the same as `vm.items[indexOfItem] =
>   newValue`, but will also trigger state updates in the reactivity
>   system:
>
> // Vue.set `Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)`

^ state updates in the reactivity system is exactly what I think Im suffering from.

Comment: I'm a Vue noob too, so apologies if this is a dumb idea, but what happens if you hardcode the idx? Could the solution be something like `that.pickedItems[that.idx] = ajaxResponse.pickedItems;`

Comment: `searchForContent` is a `method` right? You should not need to capture `var that = this;`, you can use arrow functions or even `Function#bind`. Your `v-for` seems to be missing `:key`. It would be really good if you could make a working minimal snippet (the [<>] button) of the problem, it's pretty difficult to figure out otherwise.

Comment: @Xotic750 right - `searchForContent` is a method. Why do I need `:key` for? I dont see that in vue-js examples anywhere for a loop? Not sure if I know how to quickly make an example with ajax calls and all.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: You probably need a `computed` value for `pickedItems` or a `watch`

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#ad

Comment: I've added a key and that didnt help, looking into `computed` & `watch`

Comment: Your assignment `that.pickedItems[idx] = ajaxResponse.pickedItems;` is likely not reactive. The code you commented out would apply.

Comment: @Xotic750 ahh. I fgured it out. My real problem was in how I passed data to comp1 and comp2, misunderstood the idea behind props.